# Perform A Laravel Redirect with Ajax Request with Parameters

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to redirect to my `verify.blade.php` page with parameters using Ajax response.

This is my Ajax code,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ 'signupUser' }}',
    method: 'post',
    data: formUserSignupData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.href = `verify/${response.auth_success}`;
    },
});
```

The route,

```
Route::view('verify', 'auth.verify')->name('verify');
```

So when the response is received it will generate like this (for example),

```
verify/kThgasaWW
```

I have already defined the route `verify` as I mentioned above. But when it redirects to `verify/{whatever token}` it throws an error saying 404 not found. Really appreciate it if somebody could help. Thanks.

Comment: First you should fetch data from your controller in success function and then redirect with related data or you should define parameters in your JS script if it is static or generate random token in JS script and send it with your uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below artisan command to check if the route exists.

```bash
php artisan route:list
```

I think you need to define a route parameter.

```php
Route::view('/verify/{token}', 'auth.verify')->name('verify');
```